# String interpolation with multiline indentation

Tags: ruby, string, indentation, string-interpolation, heredoc

Given a multiline string:

```
body = "\
{
  {
    foo
  }
}"
```

I want a simple way to embed this into a larger string with indentation applying to each of its lines, so that I get a string such as this:

```
{
  {
    {
      {
        foo
      }
    }
    {
      {
        foo
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in which the substring `body` is supposed to be interpolated twice.

Doing this:

```
puts "\
{
  {
    #{body}
    #{body}
  }
}
"
```

produces:

```
{
  {
    {
  {
    foo
  }
}
    {
  {
    foo
  }
}
  }
}
```

which makes sense, but is not what I want. I can write the code to generate what I expected, but with much less nicer code.

Is there a nice way to keep the elegance of `#{}` string interpolation and gain the indentation?

Comment: First, you might like to use a `HEREDOC` instead of that multi-line string. Secondly, as you said, ruby's behaviour makes total sense here - it's performing exactly as one would expect. And thirdly, it's not common to awkwardly generate elegant whitespace by hand like this, for complex data structures... Is this an XY problem, perhaps? For example, maybe you could be using something like `JSON.pretty_generate` to do all the hard work for you here?

Comment: Reference for @TomLords [`HEREDOC`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents)

Comment: It looks like you are building a pretty printed version of a data structure. It feels to me like your example is just a simplified JSON. Is that what you are trying to do? Did you consider using something like `JSON.pretty_generate`?

Comment: Some comments and answers seem to not take into account everything I wrote in my question. Ruby's answer is correct, and _of course_ it preserved the characters before my `#{...}`, that was obviously not my question.  I don't want to generate JSON or HTML, or use a post processing tool afterwards.  I know about heredocs, I was not trying to show off by using all the bells and whistles I could that are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It would be great if this were a feature of squiggly HEREDOC which already messes with the indentation in helpful ways.

Answer (score 3):

It perfectly preserves the indentation. Your body has 2 spaces before the second opening curly. Why would you expect it to know that it’s inside two already opened curlies and should magically add some indent?

You might use your own indenter, though:

```
 indent = ->(anything, level = 0, indenter = "  ") do
   anything.split($/).map.with_index do |line, idx|
     next line if idx.zero?
     line.prepend(indenter * level)
   end.join($/)
 end

 body = "\
 {
   {
     foo
   }
 }"

 puts "\
 {
   {
     #{indent.(body, 2)}
     #{indent.(body, 2)}
   }
 }"

#⇒ {
#    {
#      {
#        {
#          foo
#        }
#      }
#      {
#        {
#          foo
#        }
#      }
#    }
#  }
```

Comment: _"Why would you expect it to [...] magically add some indent?"_ – because it's Ruby 

Comment: @Stefan sometimes I hate this feeling of “everything will be done for you automagically” that almost all modern languages bring to our minds.

Comment: "Why would you expect it to know that it’s inside two already opened curlies and should magically add some indent?"  I certainly didn't...  Do you really think someone could ask such a question? You might have noticed that `#{body}` was indented; that's what I'd like to preserve.

Comment: And you have a first line of the body content indented. Still, to know how to indent the whole content that might have line breaks, the engine should look behind till the beginning of line, which would I guess drastically slow down the interpolation in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you wanted, but a nice compromise between readability and simplicity of implementation, assuming you use ActiveSupport:

```
body = "\
{
  {
    foo
  }
}"

puts "\
{
  {
#{body.indent(4)}
#{body.indent(4)}
  }
}
"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this feature!  But I'm not using ActiveSupport either.